# Introduce a sequence in descent order

Tags: postgresql, sequence

I create a sequence that I should introduce in a table order by other column in descent order.

This sequence I created like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_athlete_id 
INCREMENT BY 1 
START WITH 1001 
NO CYCLE 
OWNED BY tb_athlete.id;
```

I assigned to this table:

```
CREATE TABLE olympic.tb_athlete    (
  id CHARACTER INTEGER NOT NULL,
  athlete_id    CHARACTER(7) NOT NULL,
  name          CHARACTER VARYING(50) NOT NULL,
  country       CHARACTER VARYING(3) NOT NULL,
  substitute_id  CHARACTER(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_athlete PRIMARY KEY (athlete_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_athlete_substitute FOREIGN KEY (substitute_id) REFERENCES olympic.tb_athlete (athlete_id)
);
```

And after that I try to introduce with this code:

```
SELECT setval('seq_athlete_id'::text,
               (SELECT athlete_id 
                 FROM tb_athlete 
                 ORDER BY athlete_id DESC)::bigint);
```

But returns an error "more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression".

Because I need to introduce id order in opposite of athlete_id, it's means, athlete_id should go from maximun to minimun and id from minimun to maximun.

How can I introduce an order for apply this sequence?

Comment: You mean instead of starting the sequence at 1001, you want to start it at the maximum value of  `athlete_id` in the  `tb_athlete` table?

Comment: yes, you are right. The target is order in descent order this column of athlete_id

Comment: the "more than one row returned ..." can be solved by adding ` LIMIT 1` at the end of your subquery   (see: [LIMIT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/queries-limit.html))

Answer (score 3):

You can define your [sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-createsequence.html), so nextval() returns a lower next value each time:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_athlete_id 
INCREMENT BY -1 
START WITH 1001 
MAXVALUE 1001 
NO CYCLE ;
```

Now selecting nextval() will give:

```
select nextval('seq_athlete_id');

 nextval
---------
    1001

(1 row)

select nextval('seq_athlete_id');

 nextval
---------
    1000

(1 row)

select nextval('seq_athlete_id');

 nextval
---------
     999

(1 row)
```

Comment: But I need start with 1001 and increase it. My main problem is start with bigger number of athlete_id in descent order.

Comment: I am not a native English speaker, and confused "descent" with "descending" (sorry!). But can you explain how a "descent order" looks like ?

Comment: Yes, don't worry. Column athlete_id has values of char(7) and I need that order of this column for assign this sequence be like this 1281372-> 1281209 ->1280365-> ...

Comment: I think I need to delete my answer.  Can you [edit] the question, and provide the definition for the table `tb_athlete`, and a description of what you need. A sequence is use to determine a **new** `athlete_id`, and ordering of the athletes should be done with the `ORDER BY` in your sql statement. (Where the `ORDER BY` determines the sequence in which the athletes are shown).

Comment: I already edit for explain better my question. Because as you mention, in the moment that introduce setvalue, I try to `ORDER BY athlete_id DESC` but appear this error "more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression".

Comment: OK, I also added a comment (now 8 hours ago) to the question, (about LIMIT...) you might have missed that?

Answer (score 0):

At least I can get a solution with this Code:

```
UPDATE tb_athlete SET id = nextval('seq_athlete_id') 
FROM (SELECT athlete_id FROM tb_athlete ORDER BY athlete_id DESC) sub
WHERE tb_athlete.athlete_id = sub.athlete_id;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).